# Extra 0xFFFFFF during xor encryption

Tags: c, encryption, xor

I have this piece of code here

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define LEN 10

char buf[] = {0xff,0xaa,0xfc,0xe8,0x89,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x60,0x89};
char key[] = "SAMPLE KEY";

int main()
{
        int i;
        char enc[LEN];
        for(i=0;i<LEN;i++)
        {
                enc[i] = (key[i % LEN] ^ buf[i]);
                printf("0x%x,",enc[i]);
        }
}
```

Which outputs

**OUTPUT**

```
0xffffffac,0xffffffeb,0xffffffb1,0xffffffb8,0xffffffc5,0x45,0x20,0x4b,0x25,0xffffffd0
```

where the expected output is

```
0xac,0xeb,0xb1,0xb8,0xc5,0x45,0x20,0x4b,0x25,0xd0,
```

*How can I fix this ?
Why does this happen ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `buf` and `enc` type at declaration from `char` to `unsigned char`.

It is implementation-defined whether `char` is a `signed` or `unsigned` type and in your implementation it is apparently a `signed` type.

Comment: This works because anything with the sign bit set (bit 7) will get extended by an implicit conversion with the output functions.

Comment: +1 Thanks, That worked like charm, but would you mind explaining why we have this issue...

Comment: @vikkyhacks: You overflowed the value a `char` can hold. In your implementation, `char` is signed, and it is almost certainly eight-bit two’s complement. This means it can only hold values from –128 to 127.  The source text `0xff` stands for the number 255, which is larger than your `char` can hold. Therefore, it overflowed. In your C implementation, it stored the bits 11111111 in the char. These bits represent the value –1. When a signed `char` with value –1 is passed to `printf`, it is promoted to an `int`. The result is an `int` with value –1, which is represented with bits 0xffffffff.

Comment: @vikkyhacks: Additionally, you then printed this `int` using `%x`, which is a specifier for `unsigned int`. If you want to print with the `%x` specifier, you should convert the value to `unsigned int` before passing it to `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your encryption works fine.  You problem is that you've declared `enc` as an array of *signed* chars.  (As ouah correctly notes, `char` can be either signed or unsigned by default.  On your compiler, it's apparently signed.)

Thus, chars like `0xAC` which have their MSB set are interpreted as negative numbers.  When you pass them to `printf()`, they're implicitly converted to ints, and therefore [sign-extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) to 32 bits.

To fix it, just declare `enc`, `key` and `buf` explicitly as arrays of `unsigned char`s.  Alternatively, you could use Ben Voigt's solution and mask off the extra bits, but then you'd be pointlessly sign-extending your chars just to mask those extra bits off again.

Ps. You do realize that this kind of "encryption" is hopelessly weak if you're encrypting anything significantly longer than the key, right?

Comment: thanks your comment about encryption. I am planning to use a key as long as the text itself, I know that's a bad idea but I find it good in my case here. It is simple, fast and easy to work with than some complex encryption techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you not only have leading sign-extended bits, but also missing leading zeros.

Use

```
printf("0x%02x,", enc[i] & 0xFFu);
```

Comment: (a) The OP does not indicate leading zeroes are desired. (b) This does not fix the implementation-defined behavior of initializing signed `char` objects with values that overflow.

Comment: @Eric: The declaration of `buf` in the original source is a strong hint that yes, leading zeros are desired.

Answer (score 0):

OP is using a format meant `%x` for `unsigned`.

Since a `char` value becomes an `int` with `printf()` ... parameters, use a format `%hhx` meant for `char`.  This will print only the `char` portion.  Example:

```
printf("0x%02hhx,",enc[i]);  --> 0xac,
```

Comment: This does not fix the implementation-defined behavior of initializing signed `char` objects with values that overflow. Additionally, it leaves the objects defined as `char`, which will have negative values and give surprising results in other situations, such as bit shifting.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  I concur that the OP code has the overflow issue you mentioned - but that did not cause this problem.  Agree about bit-shifting concern is correct, but OP's snippet does not use shifting.  I supposed that the OP wanted to use `char` for some unspecified valid reason.  The issue OP had was with printing would be solved with the `hhx` format.  This which could be used with the OP's `char` or an `unsigned char`.